# "Design Mode" preprocessor directive

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, preprocessor

I have a [problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/winformsdesigner/thread/29383926-3DD1-4732-88A0-3148FD3F3B2D) on displaying a component in Designer.

I identified the "bad" code that the designer does not like.

Now, the problem is that I can't "comment" it for design time only using preprocessor directives.

Now, I tried (for VB.NET) the following

```
#If Not Debug Then
Private Sub myWpfComponent_ItsEvent(sender, args) Handles myWpfComponent.ItsEvent
...
#End If
```

this... worked, and now it is displayed without problems in the designer.

The problem now that I am afraid do not be able to **debug** properly this component.

So, I am searching for a workaround à la

```
#If Not DESIGN_TIME Then
#End If
```

Is there something similar?

Comment: @Daniel A. White: See the link on the "problem" word. Winforms Designer "don't like" handling events on a Wpf hosted Control.

Comment: I don't understand why it's necessary to do this with a preprocessor directive. What's wrong with the [`DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.getisindesignmode.aspx)?

Answer (score 13):

You cannot achieve this through the preprocessor.  This is because you can run a debug executable outside of VS (try it, double click on the EXE generated by VS under debug mode).

Anyway, there is a runtime (not preprocessor based) property that might help:

```
if (System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode ==
    System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
```

These web pages will help and have other methods of checking for design mode at runtime:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c58hb4bw(vs.71).aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2005/03/23/395658.aspx

Comment: Based on OP's mention of "myWpfComponent_ItsEvent", this looks like a WPF question. The property you mentioned is for WinForms, not WPF.

Comment: The pages referenced have other ways of checking for design more, check the second link

Comment: I can use "if" only inside a method. Not outside it :)

Comment: @serhio: Then you have a fundamental design problem. If you want to truly fix it, then change your design to something the compiler can see (we can't tell you how to do that without seeing all of your code). If you want to put a band aid over it and get it working for the time being, then use the DEBUG preprocessor symbol and then only distribute in release mode, or define your own preprocessor symbols and fix the symptom that way.

Comment: This property was very useful to me (for another reason) +1

Answer (score 4):

The IDE doesn't rebuild your code to show the designer. It uses the binary that you've already built. So a preprocessor directive won't help.

Since you mention `myWpfComponent_ItsEvent`, I assume this is a WPF question. In WPF, you detect design mode by using [GetIsInDesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.getisindesignmode.aspx).

Comment: yes. But take a look once again on my code. I need to "ignore" a entire method, or Handles in VB, or event attachement in C#. I can't use classic "if" **outside** a method (to ignore all the method)

Comment: Why do you need to do it outside the method? Just add `if (DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode(this)) return;` as the first thing in your method. Voilà: your method no longer does anything in design mode.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
{
   //Code to not execute in design mode
}
```

Note that "this" identifier can be any DependencyObject

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is using a WPF control written in VB.NET in the WinForms designer.  If the event handler is causing problems, you can use `AddHandler` instead of `WithEvents` and `Handles` to conditionalize your handler code.  Once you are using `AddHandler` you can wrap adding the handler in a `If` using the methods described in @gmagana's answer.

See this answer for the difference between Handles and AddHandler:

- [Handles vs. AddHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567/handles-vs-addhandler)

Comment: Say, the WPF control is written in C#, but the host control is in VB :). Anyway, I thought about this solution that seems to be the only  to work. thanks.