# Release vs Debug Mode in IDE

Tags: java, ide, release-management

I've always wondered what the different "deployment modes" (Release Mode, Debug Mode, etc.) were in various IDEs (Visual Studio, Netbeans, etc.). I'm sure they mean different things based on the languages and platforms the IDE supports, but there has to be a common underlying intention with marking a project as "Debug" as opposed to "Release" Mode.

What's the difference between these modes? How does the IDE treat them differently at compile/run/deployment time? Is there a way for you to customize your own Mode ("Dev Mode", "QA Mode", etc.)? If so, what are typical custom setups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Typically Debug Mode contains all possible forms of debugging information, which are stripped out in the Release Modes.

This is an inheritance from native languages like C where you run the code you generate.  It is much less a problem with Java as the typical usage is through a JVM doing an additional compilation step.

Debugging information may be very handy even for a Release Mode build, as it allows the JVM to provide more detailed information in stack traces etc.

Comment: Thanks! In another response to this question, @Ralph also mentions that Release Mode strips out this so-called "debugging information". Can you (or anybody else!) elaborate on what this information is and what it consists of? Let's take NetBeans/Java for instance. Thanks!

Comment: Debug information for Java classes is as far as I know, line number information for the byte code, and the names of local variables and parameters.  Very, very useful when stepping through in a debugger even without the source.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you recommend keeping a "Debug" version of a production component so that, even in a prod environment where you dont have access to the source, you can still attach a debugger to it and make use of the debug info? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In certain IDEs (Mostly C,C++) debug mode also initializes variables to 0. You need to keep that in mind if something works in debug mode and not in Release mode.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you can use this mode to switch on and off some debugging information (logging).

As far as I remember right: In .net / Visual Studio you can use it for example even to define sections of code that are compiled in dependence to some variables controlled by this mode. @see ["Design Mode" preprocessor directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821682/design-mode-preprocessor-directive)

Comment: Thanks @Ralph! Are generated logs the only type of debug info that gets omitted in Release Mode, or is there more "stuff"? As for the logs, what kinds of debug-type logs does, say, NetBeans produce and what's in these logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can put `debug="off"` in *build.xml* file.

Indicates whether source should be compiled with debug information; defaults to off.